# project reactor calling multiple apis based on conditions and aggregating result

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, project-reactor

I am new to reactive programming and I am developing an API that aggregates the responses of 3 other APIs. The provided interfaces are as follows:

```
public interface UserServiceApi {
    Mono<UserDetailsResponse> getUserDetails(String userId);
}
. . . 
public interface OrderServiceApi {
    Mono<OrdersResponse> getOrdersByUserId(String userId);
}
. . . 
public interface VoucherServiceApi {
    Mono<VouchersResponse> getVouchers(String userId);
}
```

The API i am working on is supposed to fetch user details, get orders by user id if signup is complete, and get vouchers for user if the user status is verified. Aggregate all this data, transform where required and return a Mono.

I want to make a call to user details api, and once the response if here make async calls to both order service and voucher service.
Here's how the code looks like right now:

```
public Mono<SuperApiResponse> getDetails(final String userId) {
    userServiceApi.getUserDetails(userId).flatMap(userDetailsResponse -> {
        final SuperApiResponse response = new SuperApiResponse();
        response.setUserDetails(userDetailsResponse);
        if(userDetailsResponse.isSignupComplete) {
            Mono<OrderResponse> orderResponse = ordersServiceApi.getOrdersByUserId(userId);
            // have to transform this OrderResponse object to another type
        }
        if(userDetailsResponse.isVerified) {
            Mono< VouchersResponse> orderResponse = voucherServiceApi.getVouchers(userId);
            // have to transform this VouchersResponse object to another type
        }
        // how to populate response of these 2 apis in the final response mono object?
        return Mono.just(response);
    })
}
```

How to aggregate response of these 3 apis while getting the most out of reactive programming? How to make these calls asynchronously?
What are the best practices for such a scenario?
Any good and easy to comprehend reading material for someone who's completely new to reactive programming?

Comment: Had the exact scenario and used `Mono.zip(getOrdersByUserId(userDetailsResponse), getVouchers(userDetailsResponse))` in conjunction with `filter()` and `defaultIfEmpty()`. I believe there is a better way...

Answer (score 1):

As stated in Serg comment using a combination of flatMap/zipWith/defaultIfEmpty is the way to go I think.

Reactor offers many tools however, so I will provide an example that allows to trigger concurrently voucher and order requests concurrently by using cached monos instead of zipWith:

```java
package fr.amanin.stackoverflow;

import java.util.logging.Logger;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public class ReactorZipServiceResults {

    static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("");

    static final UserServiceApi userApi = new UserServiceApi();
    static final OrderServiceApi orderApi = new OrderServiceApi();
    static final VoucherServiceApi voucherApi = new VoucherServiceApi();

    public static void test(String userId) throws InterruptedException {
        final PseudoTimer timer = new PseudoTimer();
        // First, sign up user. Cache will cause any caller to get back result of any previous call on this Mono
        final Mono<UserDetailsResponse> userDetails = userApi.getUserDetails(userId)
                .doOnNext(next -> LOGGER.info("Queried user details at "+timer.time()))
                .cache();

        // Separately define pipeline branch that queries orders.
        final Mono<OrdersResponse> userOrders = userDetails
                .filter(it -> it.isSignupComplete())
                .flatMap(it -> orderApi.getOrdersByUserId(userId))
                .doOnNext(next -> LOGGER.info("Queried orders at "+timer.time()))
                .cache();

        // Pipeline branch serving for vouchers
        final Mono<VouchersResponse> userVouchers = userDetails
                .filter(it -> it.isVerified())
                .flatMap(it -> voucherApi.getVouchers(userId))
                .doOnNext(next -> LOGGER.info("Queried vouchers at "+timer.time()))
                .cache();

        // Prefetch orders and vouchers concurrently, so any following call will just get back cached values.
        // Note that it will also trigger user detail query (as they're derived from it)
        userOrders.subscribe();
        userVouchers.subscribe();

        // exagerate time lapse between request triggering and result assembly.
        Thread.sleep(20);

        LOGGER.info("Pipeline assembly at "+timer.time());
        // Assemble entire pipeline by concatenating all intermediate results sequentially
        userDetails
                .map(details -> new UserProfile(userId).details(details))
                .flatMap(profile -> userOrders.map(profile::orders).defaultIfEmpty(profile))
                .flatMap(profile -> userVouchers.map(profile::vouchers).defaultIfEmpty(profile))
                .subscribe(result -> {
                    LOGGER.info("result: " + result);
                });

        // Wait all operations to finish
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
        LOGGER.warning("No call to order or voucher API");
        test("00");
        LOGGER.warning("One call to order and none to voucher API");
        test("10");
        LOGGER.warning("No call to order but one to voucher API");
        test("01");
        LOGGER.warning("Call both order and voucher API");
        test("11");
    }

    private static class PseudoTimer {
        final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        public long time() {
            return System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Mock APIS
     */

    /**
     * Simulate user details service: expects user ids with at least 2 characters.
     * If and only if the first  character is 1, the user will be considered signed up.
     * If and only if the second character is 1, the user will be considered verified.
     */
    private static class UserServiceApi {
        Mono<UserDetailsResponse> getUserDetails(String userId) {
            return Mono.just(
                    new UserDetailsResponse(userId.charAt(0) == '1', userId.charAt(1) == '1')
            );
        }
    }

    private static class OrderServiceApi {
        Mono<OrdersResponse> getOrdersByUserId(String userId) { return Mono.just(new OrdersResponse()); }
    }

    private static class VoucherServiceApi {
        Mono<VouchersResponse> getVouchers(String userId) { return Mono.just(new VouchersResponse()); }
    }

    private static class UserDetailsResponse {

        private final boolean isSignupComplete;
        private final boolean isVerified;

        private UserDetailsResponse(boolean isSignupComplete, boolean isVerified) {
            this.isSignupComplete = isSignupComplete;
            this.isVerified = isVerified;
        }

        boolean isSignupComplete() { return isSignupComplete; }

        boolean isVerified() { return isVerified; }

        public String toString() {
            return String.format("signed: %b ; verified: %b", isSignupComplete, isVerified);
        }
    }

    private static class OrdersResponse {}

    private static class VouchersResponse {}

    private static class UserProfile {
        final String userId;
        final UserDetailsResponse details;
        final OrdersResponse orders;
        final VouchersResponse vouchers;

        public UserProfile(String userId) {
            this(userId, null, null, null);
        }

        public UserProfile(final String userId, UserDetailsResponse details, OrdersResponse orders, VouchersResponse vouchers) {
            this.userId = userId;
            this.details = details;
            this.orders = orders;
            this.vouchers = vouchers;
        }

        public UserProfile details(final UserDetailsResponse details) {
            return new UserProfile(userId, details, orders, vouchers);
        }

        public UserProfile orders(final OrdersResponse orders) {
            return new UserProfile(userId, details, orders, vouchers);
        }

        public UserProfile vouchers(final VouchersResponse vouchers) {
            return new UserProfile(userId, details, orders, vouchers);
        }

        public String toString() {
            return String.format(
                    "User %s ; %s ; Orders fetched: %b ; Vouchers fetched: %b",
                    userId, details, orders != null, vouchers != null
            );
        }
    }
}
```

The output gives:

```
WARNING: No call to order or voucher API
INFO: Queried user details at 175
INFO: Pipeline assembly at 195
INFO: result: User 00 ; signed: false ; verified: false ; Orders fetched: false ; Vouchers fetched: false
WARNING: One call to order and none to voucher API
INFO: Queried user details at 0
INFO: Queried orders at 1
INFO: Pipeline assembly at 21
INFO: result: User 10 ; signed: true ; verified: false ; Orders fetched: true ; Vouchers fetched: false
WARNING: No call to order but one to voucher API
INFO: Queried user details at 0
INFO: Queried vouchers at 2
INFO: Pipeline assembly at 24
INFO: result: User 01 ; signed: false ; verified: true ; Orders fetched: false ; Vouchers fetched: true
WARNING: Call both order and voucher API
INFO: Queried user details at 0
INFO: Queried orders at 2
INFO: Queried vouchers at 3
INFO: Pipeline assembly at 25
INFO: result: User 11 ; signed: true ; verified: true ; Orders fetched: true ; Vouchers fetched: true
```